# Virtual Key Press in macOS in Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, keypress

I'm new to Swift coding, and I'm trying to create a simple Mac app in which I open some apps, switch to a new Space, open some more apps, etc.

I've settled on trying to emulate a virtual key press in order to switch to a pre-created Space. (On my system it's set up so that "ctrl-a" switches to the first space, "ctrl-b" the second and so on.

Previous searches here have gotten me the following code:

```
func keyPress(letterKeyCode: CGKeyCode) {
   let controlKeyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(kVK_Control), keyDown: true)
   controlKeyDownEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
   controlKeyDownEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

   let letterKeyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: letterKeyCode, keyDown: true)
   letterKeyDownEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
   letterKeyDownEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

   let letterKeyUpEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: letterKeyCode, keyDown: false)
   letterKeyUpEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
   letterKeyUpEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

   let controlKeyUpEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(kVK_Control), keyDown: false)
   controlKeyUpEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
   controlKeyUpEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `maskCommand` is Command Key, use `maskControl`. Is App Sandbox switched off?

Comment: That did it, Willeke, thanks very much!