# Swift MacOS App with virtual key presses loses focus after one event

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

I'm working on an app for my Leica Disto laser measurement device. (There is only an official Windows version…)

It lives in the menu bar and doesn't have a dock icon. It is meant to work with any app in the foreground like excel.

The bluetooth connection is working and this is the flow:

If a new measurement is triggered on the device it copies the data to the clipboard. After that I pastes it by using the virtual key presses for "CMD+V" and also "Enter" to go to the next line. (Found here: [Virtual Key Press in macOS in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616754/virtual-key-press-in-macos-in-swift-4))

The problem is, that after the first virtual key press event the "focus" is lost. The next measurement will paste somewhere else depending on the application in the foreground. (In numbers it will paste es a new text field over the spreadsheet.) I first have click into the next cell. Then it works again.

Sometimes it even works for two consecutive measurements.

I already experimented with delays between the key presses but that did not help. I also check if accessibility access is granted at startup. Any idea?

MacOS BigSur

```
func paste() {

    let event1 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: true); // cmd-v down
    event1?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand

    let event2 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: false) // cmd-v up
    event2?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand

    event1?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    usleep(100)
    event2?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    usleep(100)
}

func pressEnterKey() {

    let enterKeyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(0x24), keyDown: true)

    let enterKeyUpEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(0x24), keyDown: false)

    enterKeyDownEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    usleep(100)
    enterKeyUpEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    usleep(100)
    print("Enter")
}

func checkAndAskForAssistiveAccess() {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675555/how-to-grant-accessibilty-access-in-xcode
    //get the value for accesibility
    let checkOptPrompt = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as NSString
    //set the options: false means it wont ask
    //true means it will popup and ask
    let options = [checkOptPrompt: true]
    //translate into boolean value
    let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options as CFDictionary?)

    if accessEnabled == true {
        print("Access Granted")
    } else {
        print("Access not allowed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing the command key?

Comment: Hm, what exactly do you mean? When should CMD be pressed?

Comment: Like on a real keyboard, Command down, V down, V up, Command up. See [Virtual Key Press in macOS in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616754/virtual-key-press-in-macos-in-swift-4).